# Vuex - changing value based on component's current index and passing the value to other components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have hit a wall and cannot get over it without your help now. I've spent a good few days trying to get my head around mutations and actions but this particular case I have doesn't seem to apply to tutorials online, also the answers on here are for different scenarios to mine. So here goes:

Setup:
- Project is using vuex and store for data and state management
- Currently App.vue has two child components: PizzaGenerator.vue and BaseButtons.vue

I am trying to achieve this:
- When I click on a specific button in BaseButtons.vue I need a centrally managed showBaseIndex to be assigned an index value. This value is then available to the other, PizzaGenerator.vue, component which will reflect the change and show a layer that matches the new value of showBaseIndex.

Please see all the two components and store below.

Can you help me head in the right direction?

PizzaGenerator.vue

```
<template>
<div class="pizza-generator section" id="screen3" data-anchor="screenThree">
    <ul class="pizza-layers">
        <!-- Display pizzas -->
        <li v-for="(item, index) in getBase" class="pizza-canvas pizza-canvas--base" v-bind:class="item.class"  v-if="$store.state.showBaseIndex == index"></li>
        <!-- END Display pizzas -->
    </ul>

    <div class="pizza-items">
        <app-base-buttons></app-base-buttons>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Base from './pizza-buttons/BaseButtons'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
components: {
    appBaseButtons: Base
},
computed: {
    getBase(){
        return this.$store.state.base
    }
},
methods: mapActions([
    'baseLayer',
]),
}
</script>
```

BaseButtons.vue

```
   <div class="pizza-items-selector pizza-items-selector--dough">
    <div class="pizza-items-selector__items pizza-items-selector__items--dough">
        <div class="sliding-buttons">
            <button v-for="(item, index) in getBase" class="sliding-buttons__button dough-button" :key="index" @click="baseLayer = index"> {{ item.name }}</button>
        </div>
        <button class="buttons-prev-1 prev">prev</button>
        <button class="buttons-next-1 next">next</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
export default {
computed:{ 
    getBase(){
        return this.$store.state.base
    },
},
methods:{ 
    ...mapMutations([
        'baseLayer',
    ]),
    baseLayerIndex() {
        this.$store.commit('baseLayer');
    }
},
```

}

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    showBaseIndex: 1,
    base : [
        { name: 'Dünner Italienisch', class: 'pizza-canvas--base-italienisch', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Dünner Italienisch - Vollkorn', class: 'pizza-canvas--base-italienisch--vollkorn', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Dicker Amerikanisch', class: 'pizza-canvas--base-amerikanisch', id: 3 },
        { name: 'Dicker Amerikanisch / Chili-Käse-Rand', class: 'pizza-canvas--base-amerikanisch--chilli-kaese-rand', id: 4 },
        { name: 'Dicker Amerikanisch / Käse-Rand', class: 'pizza-canvas--base-amerikanisch--kaese-rand', id: 5 }
    ],
},
getters: {
    //
},
mutations: {
    baseLayer (state){
        state.showBaseIndex
    }
}, 
});
export default store;
```

Comment: I believe you wrote `store.js` code in `PizzaGenerator.vue` code could you edit you question?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the PizzaGenerator.vue That was fairly ignorant of me not to check the code before posting. Apologies.

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutations are functions, not simple values. You should check the Vuex [guide about mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html), they are quite straightforward.

What you should do is declaring the given mutation in this way, so it will also accept a parameter:

```
mutations: {
    baseLayer (state, id){
        state.showBaseIndex = id;
    }
},
```

and commit the mutation properly in the component:

```
    methods:{ 
    ...mapMutations([
        'baseLayer',
    ]),
    baseLayerIndex(index) { // call this at @click on button, giving the index as parameter
        this.$store.commit('baseLayer', index);
    }
    }
```

This will set the desired index in the store, and from that on you could get the current base from store using vuex getters like:

```
getters: {
    getSelectedBase(state){
      return state.base.find(base=>{return base.id === state.showBaseIndex});
    }
},
```

Comment: Great, Ábel, this worked, didn't even have to use the getters in the end. The main learning is to remember that mutations are functions. Many thanks!